# android build error: can't find symbol class IntDef

Tags: java, android, dependencies, implementation

Using Android Studio to build the android version of a react native app.  I just received

> 'error: cannot find symbol class IntDef'

It's used in the following code:

```
@IntDef(flag = true, value = { Information.BATTERY, Information.RSSI, Information.API_VERSION, Information.LED,
            Information.APPLICATION_VERSION })
```

the bottom of my dependencies block looks like this:

```
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

Do I need to make an import at the top of this file..or is do I need to add to the build.gradle such as     `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'`

inside the dependencies block?

I had the same issues except it was with ArrayMap, this was fixed by adding

```
compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.0"
```

in the dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably will have to include the following in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}
```

And the import statement in your class would be such :

```
import android.support.annotation.IntDef;
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work by adding import androidx.annotation.IntDef;
 to the top of the file. I failed to realize that it was needed in two different places.  Thanks for your help.